# How to stop an imageView loading a remote image?

Tags: titanium, appcelerator

Is there a way to tell an imageView to stop loading a remote image?

This would be an image loaded with the image property of an imageView

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured it out by setting the imageView.image = null;